# suggestions please: keychain to retain ssh key passphrase across reboots

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, raspbian

I want to use ssh on a raspberry pizeroW to make persistent on-boot sshfs mounts to a central fileserver machine.

I do not want the pi's mount target to query id_rsa passphrase every login/boot/mount.

In kubuntu I use kwallet to remember the key passphrase, so simply by logging into the GUI all of my sshfs mounts work without passphrase query.

I want to do the same/similar on the headless and generally unattended pizero, which is console only (no GUI).

There is a kwalletcli package, but thats 250MiB of associated software, which seems excessive for a pizero, and i'm not even sure if it's going to work, or is the appropriate package.

I've tried the 'keychain' package, and that almost does what I want, except that it queries key passphrase on each reboot. That's exactly what i need it to NOT do.

Suggestions please.

Comment: Why not just remove the passphrase protecting the private key? That's a fairly common solution between systems that have a trust relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I'm never a fan of that solution.I opted for NFS in this case.